# Examples of using authlib's httpx client asynchronously

Tags: python, python-asyncio, authlib, httpx

There are several examples [here](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/client/oauth2.html) of using an `httpx` client instead of a `requests` based session with the popular oauth lib, `authlib`

However in those examples, they don't show how to properly open and close an async `httpx` session. See https://www.python-httpx.org/async/

When I try to use it as suggested, I get warnings either about the session not being closed:

> UserWarning: Unclosed <authlib.integrations.httpx_client.oauth2_client.AsyncOAuth2Client object at 0x000001B6444BFEB0>. See https://www.python-httpx.org/async/#opening-and-closing-clients for details

And if I call twice, I get

> RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

This makes complete sense to me, as the examples in `authlib`s docs aren't using a context manager for the async session

Comment: Can you show a minimal example of _your_ code that's not working as you'd like? For example, it's not clear what you mean by "if I call twice".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`authlib`'s `AsyncOAuth2Client`  inherits from `httpx`'s `AsyncClient`, so you should be able to use the same methods given at https://www.python-httpx.org/async/#opening-and-closing-clients. So either something like:

```
async with authlib.integrations.httpx_client.oauth2_client.AsyncOAuth2Client() as client:
    ...
```

or:

```
client = authlib.integrations.httpx_client.oauth2_client.AsyncOAuth2Client()
...
await client.aclose()
```

Should allow you to open and close sessions as needed.